# Spline fitting to data how to predict for particular value

Tags: spline

After fitting a spline model

```
fit<-lm(wage ~ bs(age,knots = c(30,50,60)),data = Wage)
```

how to predict for particular age?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
predict (fit ,newdata =list(age = 30))
```

Now you will ask how I know age should be 30. 
One word for you - 'Magic'